# Web Crawler - Windows Form Exe Application - Getting Blocked

Tags: c#, winforms, web-crawler

I am working on windows form application containing Web Browser Control which basically crawls a list of webpages and then extracts data from it using DOM.

When I am Crawling a particular website I am always getting blocked after exactly 100 Links. The Error message that I am getting when blocked says "Your Visit has been terminated".

I have 6 Public IPs(All different range) that I am cycling through every 20 Links. I have confirmed that the IPs are actually getting changed.

Also after every 20 Links I am resetting complete IE history,Cookies,Website data,Temporary Internet Files,etc using this code

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255");
```

I am also making the application wait before navigating next link for about 2 second to 8 second using random class in c#.

What my question is I don't understand at all why I am still getting blocked?
I am cycling the IPs.
All link navigation request are at random interval.

Is there anything at application level that I am missing?or is it something else?

Comment: Whats the website? or better yet, do you get this error if you do the operation manually?

Comment: change your web client every time

Comment: @JeremyThompson Manually I tried Opening more than 100 Links,continously openning new tab in Chrome browser , but it is working there.  here is one of the link http://goo.gl/S5xard

Comment: @SimiTKD I am using web browser control in my application. How can i change web client? I am not getting you

Comment: by changing your web browser that your program uses for crawler

Comment: @SimiTKD I tried using multiple browsers, but that too didn't worked. :(

Comment: add time delay  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(); you should use10+second delay sever blocks you may because you are fetching data too fast

Comment: @SimiTKD I already mentioned above that I am making my application wait for 2 to 8 seconds randomly

Comment: Looks like they detect screen scrapping, try changing the headers you use to match the ones of a web browser used in the manual scrapping.

Comment: @JeremyThompson By changing the headers you mean changing the User Agent?

Comment: Yes, UserAgent - thats what I was thinking of

Comment: @JeremyThompson i tried changing user agent using the code 

`[DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int UrlMkSetSessionOption(
    int dwOption, string pBuffer, int dwBufferLength, int dwReserved);

const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT = 0x10000001;
const int URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH = 0x10000002;

public void ChangeUserAgent()
{
    string ua = "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)";

    UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT_REFRESH, null, 0, 0);
    UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, ua, ua.Length, 0);` 
but didn't worked